# Can MySQL connect to Remote SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, mysql

Can MySQL access a remote SQL Server database through ODBC or similar connector? I've seen many articles on the reverse path, accessing MySQL from SQL Server.

Comment: Not implemented. Only remote MySQL server can be accessed (using FEDERATED Engine).

Comment: Not exactly like SSMS does but you may use a third-party tool to manage both instances like DBeaver through ODBC/JDBC. Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: The user can take a look at mariadb https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-odbc-table-type-accessing-tables-from-another-dbms/

Comment: You can do the other way around: connect SSMS to MySQL and withdraw the data from there if this is what you are trying to do: https://superuser.com/questions/163610/anyway-to-use-ssms-to-connect-to-mysql